# Select by expression doesn't work - QGIS

Tags: qgis, select, expression

I want to make a "selection by expression", as shown on the screenshot.

I choose the FIELD and the VALUE from the side panel, but it's selecting 0 rows (there are actually more than 100...).

[image: screen shot]

I just don't see why.

Comment: Make sure you click 'select' in the bottom right corner - the output preview isn't doing the selection for you...

Comment: +1 @mapBaker! This is true, sometimes the Output preview is not a good indication of the result. Always click `Select`! Let us know if this was the issue so that we can help to find out something else, if not.

Comment: Can you confirm your QGIS version?

Comment: Thank you both! I am sure I "hammered" on the select button without anything to happen... But now I am at home on a different system, and here I cannot reproduce my problem any more. Tomorrow I will check again, is that ok?! My GIS version is Lyon 2.12.1.

Comment: Well, I may have hammered the select button, at least I didn't check the result of that thoroughly enough... Indeed it's just working, although the preview still shows 0, or nothing at all. Thanks for your answers! One more question: Select by Expression works more or less the same as a Query Builder? Thanks again

Comment: Output preview does not show the number of matched features. Expressions in the query builder return True (feature is in the result set) or False (feature is not). I cannot interpret output preview in this case. When using field calculator output preview shows an example of the result, maybe the first?